# Use HTML anchor link to display a hidden div and scroll to desired anchor location

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, anchor

I'm trying to create an index page and would like to have links to anchors which would be within a hidden div.

Clicking the anchor link would trigger the div the anchor is in to become visible and scroll the page to the anchor location.

I've tried a few things but have failed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<div>
  <p>Link</p>
  <a href="#content1">Content 1</a><a href="#content2">Content 2</a><a href="#content3">Content 3</a><a href="#content4">Content 4</a>
</div>
<div class="inter">Some intermedary content with a large bottom margin to demonstrate scroll</div>
<div>
  <div class="hiddenContent">
    <div id="content1">I am content 1</div>
    <div id="content2">I am content 2</div>
    <div id="content3">I am content 3 
    <a id="content4" >Inner anchor within content 3 div. Link should scroll here but also show the other content within content 3.</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please include a working or semi-working example. describing code behavior doesn't help anyone help you.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily solved with CSS. You will need to adjust to meet your needs as you've not given us any code to work with.

Use the `:target` pesuo-class selector to select an item that is the target of a link

```css
.hiddenContent>div, .hiddenContent > [name=content4] {
  display: none;
}

.hiddenContent>div:target {
  display: block;
}

.inter {
  margin-bottom: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Link</p>
  <a href="#content1">Content 1</a><a href="#content2">Content 2</a><a href="#content3">Content 3</a><a href="#content4">Content 4</a>
</div>
<div class="inter">Some intermedary content with a large bottom margin to demonstrate scroll</div>
<div>
  <div class="hiddenContent">
    <div id="content1">I am content 1</div>
    <div id="content2">I am content 2</div>
    <div id="content3">I am content 3</div>
    <a name="content4" >
        <div>Some content in a named anchor</div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! This solves 1 issue but I'm still stuck trying to figure out how to scroll to an anchor within one of the hidden divs. Is it possivle to lin to this anchor and display the contents of the content 1 div? (<div>
  <p>Link</p>
  <a href="#content1">Content 1</a><a href="#content2">Content 2</a><a href="#content3">Content 3</a></div>
<div class="hiddenContent">
  <div id="content1">I am content 1<br/><a name"anchor1"></a>Anchor Ttitle</div>
  <div id="content2">I am content 2</div>
  <div id="content3">I am content 3</div>
</div>)

Comment: This still scrolls to the hidden target, I've modified to demontrate. Use ID on your target element from the link instead of a named anchor. I haven't seen a named anchor since the 90s. However, named anchors also work, see updated edit.

Comment: Sorry I'm new and not sure how to add HTML in comments. The issue is I need to have multiple anchors within a hidden div. When one of the anchors is clicked it should scroll the the anchor but also display the other contents within the div. See here http://prntscr.com/npm691

Comment: How to you click on something in a hidden div. If the div is hidden, so is the anchor/link.  Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56178400/edit) your question to provide a better example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Updated hope that helps clarify. Thanks again.